# Different colours in hyperref

Tags: hyperref

When using the option `colorlinks` with the hyperref package , I get the output as shown :
[image]
Now, How do I add a hyperlink to the page number also and add a different color say blue to it.

Comment: Look in the documentation for `hyperref`! http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf You can search for "page number" there for the first question for example.

Comment: Why do you want to have different colours for the same link. The reader will think, that you are having two different targets.

Answer (score 7):

I would not recommend to use two colours here. The links will both guide to the same target and therefore should look the same.

Therefore, I would recommend to colour (and link) all the same:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[%
,colorlinks % sets the link in colours (replaces the red box)
,linktoc=all % sets hyperrefs on the page numbers in the TOC 
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction to Java}
\section{The Creation of Java}
\section{How Java Changed the Internet}
\subsection{Java Applets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or you colour the page numbers for design reasons but do not make it a link:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[%
,colorlinks % sets the link in colours (replaces the red box)
]{hyperref}

\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\color{blue}}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\color{blue}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction to Java}
\section{The Creation of Java}
\section{How Java Changed the Internet}
\subsection{Java Applets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not able to get your desired result with colour and link.